# Stripe with PHP. How to charge user's card information with source

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I'm new with stripe and I'm just using the test mode because I just want to test my code if it is working before I go live, first I test this PHP code and the payment was able to found on my test Dashboard:

```
<?php
    require_once('app/init.php');

    try{
        $stripe = new \Stripe\StripeClient($stripeKey['private']);

        $stripe->charges->create([
          'amount' => 4860,
          'currency' => 'usd',
          'source' => 'tok_visa' /*The 'tok_visa' value was copied from the stripe example docs.*/
          'description' => $_REQUEST['email']
        ]);

    }catch(\Stripe\Exception\CardException $e){
        echo $e->getError()->message;
    }catch(Exception $ue){
        echo $ue->getMessage();
    }

    header('Location: index.php');
    exit();
?>
```

But when I tried to change the value of source and provided the test card information which has a number of "4242424242424242" I receive no error but the payment don't go through to my test dashboard:

```
<?php
    require_once('app/init.php');

    try{
        $stripe = new \Stripe\StripeClient($stripeKey['private']);

        $stripe->charges->create([
          'amount' => 4860,
          'currency' => 'usd',
          'source' => [
            'object' => 'card',
            'number' => $_REQUEST['cardNumber'],
            'exp_month' => intval($_REQUEST['cardExpMonth']),
            'exp_year' => intval($_REQUEST['cardExpYear']),
            'cvc' => $_REQUEST['cardSecurityNumber']
            ],
          'description' => $_REQUEST['email']
        ]);

    }catch(\Stripe\Exception\CardException $e){
        echo $e->getError()->message;
    }catch(Exception $ue){
        echo $ue->getMessage();
    }

    header('Location: index.php');
    exit();
?>
```

This is my custom test form where I imported the `<script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>` :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Premium</title>
        <script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>You are about to premium.</p>
        <form action="premium_charge.php" action="POST">
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Enter your card information:</legend>
                <span>Enter Credit Card: </span><input type="text" name="cardNumber">&nbsp &nbsp
                <span>Expiration Date: </span><input type="text" name="cardExpMonth" size="1">
                <input type="text" name="cardExpYear" size="4"><br><br>
                <span>Security: </span><input type="text" name="cardSecurityNumber" size="4"><br><br>
                <span>Email: </span><input type="email" name="email"><br><br>
                <input type="submit" name="submitBtn" value="Pay $4860">
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

I'm thinking there's something wrong with the source value, please correct me if there is and correct me how to provide a right values for source element like my website is live one let assume and charging card from what the user input in the form.

Comment: What error are you getting? Is there an API call attempt logged in the dashboard logs? Your are correct that tok_visa needs to make sense in the context of your deployment. Please post a link to which stripe example you followed.

Comment: I don't receive any error the program is successfully executed but the I don't see the payment on my dashboard test account. Here the link where I get the sample code [link](https://stripe.com/docs/api/charges/create) @ed2

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Stripe's hosted checkout at https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout.

Alternatively, if you preferred to customise the integration yourself (such as with Stripe Elements), keep reading.

You will need to pass a valid `source` (for example, a `card` object).

The process of "creating a charge" is only one part of the exercise - there are a series of steps to ensure are going through in the right order, including creating a source or payment method.

The API docs provide definitions and syntax, as well as syntax examples, for each 'step' in the process (such as creating a charge). However, elsewhere in the extensive documentation are plenty of examples of end-to-end processes, complete with code examples for each required step.

You can find them here https://stripe.com/docs/payments. There are also links to example code on GitHub that you can adapt.

I recommend looking at one of the code examples provided by Stripe, and follow that. Just pick one that suits your use case.

The examples cover a range of languages for both frontend (e.g. JavaScript) and back end (e.g. PHP). You can choose which languages suit best. If using Elements for a custom integration, you will need both a front end component and a back end component.

If you prefer not to use Elements, you could use a stripe hosted checkout. This is customisable to a degree, but has some limitations. An advantage is much less work for you, less to understand/setup/code/customise. It may be what you are looking for. You can find out more about it at https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout.

In terms of the call you are currently making, I suggest you use your browser dev tools (F12) to inspect the outgoing request and response objects (network tab) to see what you are actually sending to the API and what it is returning (e.g. error code). This will likely prove useful to narrowing down which part of your current code is causing the issue, even if you get no user-surfaced runtime errors.

Your are correct in suspecting the issue is in your use of 'tok_visa' in this case. Finding an end-to-end example should solve it.

Comment: So basically from my understanding  to your answer I need to create an object like `card` object? would you provide a simple example how to pass a valid `source` from creating an object let say `card` object.

Comment: There are some good examples here https://stripe.com/docs/payments. Choose one that seems to fit your use case the closest, then you can adapt it. It will guide you through how to capture card information and use that information to charge the card.

Comment: Yes but those examples are too complicated to understand for me a beginner one that led me to confusion that leave me a question like do I need to create Stripe Elements with Javascript before to charge the card or PHP script is enough to make a charge? what maybe I need is a example for dummy only and clarification if Javascript is a must to create a charge from the card or pure PHP is enough?

Comment: Understandable. The examples cover a range of languages for both frontend (e.g. JavaScript) and back end (e.g. PHP). You can choose which languages suit best. If using Elements for a custom integration, you will need both a front end component and a back end component. If you prefer not to use Elements, you could use a stripe hosted checkout. This is customisable to a degree, but has some limitations. An advantage is much less work for you, less to understand/setup/code/customise. It may be what you are looking for. You can find out more about it at https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout

Comment: @prototype93 if you are beginner id suggest not you to create payment forms, ones that gets the credit card numbers etc, your self. id suggest on using the  https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout (havent tried that my self) and review
https://stripe.com/docs/security

Comment: I see I understand now, in my case I chose to create a custom integration so I can design my own checkout form from scratch rather than using the prebuilt, so I need to understand how Stripe JS Elements work also right?

Comment: If you want to avoid checkout and have a custom integration from scratch, you have two choices: get someone experienced to do it for you, or do it yourself. This is a systems integration type project and involves web development under the hood. If you are doing this for the first time, you will not be able to avoid the need for a lot of learning along the way. it necessarily involves understanding how stripe works, interactions between your webpages, your server and stripe, as well as a fair bit of frontend (e.g. html, css, javaScript) and backend (e.g. PHP) development.

Comment: You would also need to be very conscious of a lot of different security facets, involving stripe, website operation and server/communications security. These directly impact how you go about coding your custom solution. If you are not already familiar with either stripe development, frontend development and website security considerations relating to custom coding (frontend and server), I would recommend either stripe checkout or outsourcing this. If doing it yourself, prepare to invest significant time getting across all of those matters.